# gnome dual monitor different workspace

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome, alt-tab

Is it possible to have different workspace on both of my screens in GNOME ? I don't want to mix the alt + tab application switching with applications in other screen, and there are already solutions to do that, but I could only apply them if I have different workspaces in both of these screens and it seems that by default both screens share the same workspace with one locked on secondary monitor.

Comment: Hey, did you find ab answer to your question?